# Feedback when typing password at a sudo prompt

Tags: command-line, unix, sudo

When I type in my password at a sudo command line prompt, I would like to see a "*" for each keystroke. How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On some UNIX-based systems, sudo can show an asterisk (*) when you type a letter.

In the terminal, enter...

```
sudo visudo;
```

Type your root password in (you won't see any visual feedback yet) and hit Enter.

Now, find the line that reads:

```
Defaults env_reset
```

And replace it with:

```
Defaults env_reset,pwfeedback
```

Finally save and exit the file. Assuming you are using vi, that command is:

```
:wq!
```

and then press Enter.

sudo should now be set up correctly. To test, open up a new terminal and type this to reset the sudo timeout.

```
sudo -k;
```

Now try it out.

```
sudo ls;
```

Source: http://whyareyoureadingthisurl.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/sudo-and-password-feedback/

Comment: Just as a PSA: `pwfeedback` is not related to `env_reset` at all. They do not have to be in the same `Defaults` statement, although they certainly can be. It's always perfectly valid to just add a new line like this: `Defaults pwfeedback`, if you prefer it this way.

Answer (score 6):

You can enable visual feedback when typing passwords by editing your `/etc/sudoers` file and changing the `Defaults` line to read:

```
Defaults    env_reset,pwfeedback
```

---

Example:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/sudoers` (edit with `sudo visudo`), add the following line:

```
Defaults pwfeedback
```

Note: the other answer all mention `env_reset`, which is an unrelated option. Depending on your config, you might not have such a line. It is not needed, and it is also fine to have multiple Defaults statements.