# Disable feedback when typing password at a sudo prompt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, passwords, sudo

When I type my password at a sudo command line prompt, it shows `*` for each keystroke recently. Is this a new default behaviour? How do I switch this off again?

There is no `pwfeedback` option set in my `/etc/sudoers` file. I am using Linux Mint 19 which is Ubuntu Bionic basically, package version of sudo is 1.8.21p2-3ubuntu1 and my sudo binary shows the same sha256 hash than the one in the package.

Thanks for any advice!

Inverted question of: [Feedback when typing password at a sudo prompt](https://superuser.com/q/420815)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this in another thread and it ensures that, if the Mint devs reintroduce this bad feature in a new update, your own modifications will override it:

The accepted answer of simply removing `/etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback` will work precisely until the next update to mintsystem puts that file back in place.

The way to revert to the old behavior, that is recommended by the person responsible for the new one, is to override the setting in a different file that gets read later:

```
echo 'Defaults !pwfeedback'|sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/9_no_pwfeedback
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491173/linux-mint-how-to-set-the-terminal-password-to-be-invisible

Answer (score 2):

After some more research on files in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory, I found the right answer here:

[Linux Mint. How to set the terminal password to be invisible?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491360)

It says:

> LinuxMint added the behavior in `/etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback`.
>   You could simply do like I did - delete the file as it contains only that adjustment:
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf /etc/sudoers.d/0pwfeedback
> ```

According to @SyntaxxxErr0r, renaming the file works as well: if it ends with a `~` or contains a `.` character, it will not be parsed.

Recently, @elsewhere suggested another solution which is more future-proof and stable across package updates and therefore I select that answer as the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify here, actually, yes, renaming the file could actually disable the file being parsed. That is, if it were to have a ~ or a . as per the README found in the directory itself:

```
# This will cause sudo to read and parse any files in the /etc/sudoers.d 
# directory that do not end in '~' or contain a '.' character.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get rid of the feedback by editing
the file `/etc/sudoers`.

Search for a line that may look like this:

```
Defaults env_reset,pwfeedback
```

and delete `,pwfeedback` from the line. Take first a backup copy of it.

You may need to reset your terminal using the command `reset`.

If this does not work, another possibility is to rename the file
`/etc/sudoers.d/pwfeedback` to something else, keeping it just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but as I wrote, there is no pwfeedback in my `sudoers` file.

Comment: You missed out on the last paragraph in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but renaming the file will not help, it will be included in the sudoers anyway. Only deleting the file will fix the problem, as I wrote in my answer. Moreover, the name of the file causing the problem is actually *0pwfeedback*.